# Is it valid and safe to use eval/Function/new Function to create an HTML template engine in Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, function, eval, template-engine

I have the following function that creates HTML from a string, within this string, which uses the syntax "$ {variable}" to add dynamic content, thus, this string is passed to the Function in order to create a new function that each once it is run and variables are passed to it, the value of "$ {variable}" will be replaced.

```
const createTemplate = (template) => Function(
    'props',
    'try { return `' + template + '`;} catch(err) { return err }'
);

const render = createTemplate('<h1>${ props.title }</h1>');

const html = render({ title: 'Welcome!' }); 

// html = '<h1>Welcome!</h1>'
```

But is this safe? Is this really safe? Are there any vulnerabilities? o Is it safe in this context? Can I be sure that this is safe?

I hope you can help generate a code with good practices :)

Comment: You don't need to do this. Just return a function: `createTemplate = (template) => (props) => {try { return template } catch (err) { return err }}` -- no function constructor needed and you'll have better support from your IDE because it now understands the syntax of your "code" instead of storing your code as a string

Comment: But what would happen if the `template` was read from an HTML file? How do I inject the `props`?

Comment: Use string processing. For example: `for (let var in props) {template = template.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\{\\s*props\\.' + var + '\\s*\\}'), props[var])}`. You're not restricted to `${var}` syntax of course. You can use `%var%` or `{{var}}` etc. Also you are free to either use `${props.var}` or simply `${var}` in your syntax.